# Is Google's Lighthouse Audit No Longer Working For The Latest Version Of Windows 10?

Tags: lighthouse

Lighthouse audit is no longer working for me. Are you having the same issue too?

Lighthouse audit is no longer working within Google chrome's browser for me. It freezes about 90% through. My boss at my work also attempted to run a lighthouse audit on the internet at work, it failed in the same way. I then tried to run the lighthouse audit from the Google Chrome browser on other websites, this also failed. Running it from my home computer also failed.

Google Chrome is Version 96.0.4664.110 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Windows 10 home, 19042.1415 is not working, I think my work has the office version, I don't know the version number.

I and my coworker were running windows 10 with the latest version of chrome and windows. I attempted to run the audit on 4 different PCs with the Google Chrome browser. Every single computer failed, the audit froze about 90% through. It did not throw an error. I have used it something like 10,000 times  I use it constantly for my work. Usually, I will open it incognito. I have done it in Factory reset computers. Lighthouse audit stopped working on chrome for me at the end of October. If it helps I use Xfinity internet. I just tried the lighthouse audit from a windows 10 computer that was at Walmart, via the google chrome browser. This also froze 90% of the way through the same as the computers on my home and work network did.

I was successfully able to launch the audit from the command prompt using node.js

Are you able to run the lighthouse audit from the chrome browser?

Comment: Works fine for me from my Chromium browser....  But how are you doing it?  I think there are lots of different ways.

Comment: `I and my coworker were running windows 10 with the latest version of chrome and windows.` I've seen reports of problems running Lighthouse around October and November. Can you edit the question to also include the version of Chrome and Windows 10? There might have been a bug fix since then, so make sure you've updated Chrome to the latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They patched this problem in January of 2022